# how to hide my api key on an upload form on php

Tags: php, post

```
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://SERVER.com/upload/02" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="API-KEY-HERE">
    <input name="file" type="file">
    <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

Is it possible to recover the file and send it to the server with another php page?

The API key should not appear!

My goal is that the key does not appear anywhere!

Comment: Is it possible for you to only access the service protected by the API Key only from the webserver via PHP? If it isn't possible and you need to create the request from the client there is no possibillity to hide it. You may ofuscate it but at the end it will be visible in the network tab of the dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send the file to your server, then your server will make a POST request which includes both API key and the file to the target server.

If you are using jquery:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $('[type=file]')[0].files[0]);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/your-current-server',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
}).done(() => console.log('upload completed'))
  .fail(e => console.log('upload failed:', e));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) , But i do not have or store the client file! I must send it directly to the address indicated on the form `action="https://SERVER.com/upload/02"`

Answer (score 0):

> it possible to recover the file and send it to the server with another php page?

Yes, it is. You can have the file uploaded to your own server where you're running your PHP script, then use an HTTP cliente like cURL to make a POST request to the API server, using your API key to communicate between servers rather than directly from the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) , But i do not have or store the client file! I must send it directly to the address indicated on the form `action="https://SERVER.com/upload/02"`

Comment: Couldn't you host a PHP script for doing that? Or are we talking about static hosting?

Comment: yes I can host a php script!
but not the file send by the user,
the file must be directly send to the form address `action =" https://SERVER.com/upload/02 "`
Without the API key the server does not accept the file

Comment: Okay, so here's what I think you could do. 1) Create a PHP script to handle the upload; 2) Point your HTML form to your script, instead of SERVER.com/...; 3) In your script, when you receive the file, it will be on a temporary folder; you can simply use cURL to make a POST request to the final destination, e.g.: SERVER.com/..., passing the API KEY in the headers and sending the file in the post body.

Comment: Does that make sense? Please let me know if that gives you any direction, so that I can edit my answer accordingly. Cheers!

Comment: sorry for the delay !
can you tell me more! I think that's it

Answer (score 0):

There has no way to hide those API key via **HTTP request**.Those hidden input/form data always visible when educated user try to inspect all the network request event from browser.

Unless you process or use the API Key inside your **server side program**.

OR

**Encrypt** it before assign to the hidden input to make it less accessible and less readable.